# InitMUILanguage() vs MessageBox()

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I have MUI C++ application that uses [`InitMUILanguage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775699(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SetProcessPreferredUILanguages()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374050(v=vs.85).aspx) for change UI language in system controls and dialogues.

All work fine, all common controls use UI language that has been set by `InitMUILanguage()`. Except `MessageBox()`. It completely ignores settings from `InitMUILanguage()` and shows buttons' text on system default language!

How to fix it?

Comment: You cant "fix" it. That is simply how `MessageBox` works. There is `MessageBoxEx` with a `wLanguageId` parameter, but MS never hooked it up.

Comment: What do you mean by "never hooked it by"? I used to MessageBoxEx with correct LangID and it had taken LangID into account. I thought MessageBox will work with InitMUILanguage too.

Comment: `InitMUILanguage` sets the language for the common controls library. This is clearly stated in its documentation. `MessageBox` is not part of the common controls library